# How to store different select value to the same variable

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is it possible to store different select value to the same variable?

```
DECLARE @cout int 

SELECT @cout= count(*) FROM Master1 WHERE (...)

SET @cout = SELECT count(*) FROM Master2 WHERE (...)

SET @cout = SELECT count(*) FROM Master3 WHERE (...)

IF(@cout = 0)
 BEGIN
 END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
IF EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM Master1 WHERE (...)
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM Master2 WHERE (...)
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM Master3 WHERE (...)
)    
BEGIN
...
END
```

It should do the trick, and pull out quickly enough...

Answer (score 0):

No, what you've got there will replace the value. You can append them as strings though, or add up the numbers. But it's bad practice; better to return a resultset, i.e:

```
SELECT
    (select count(*) FROM Master1 WHERE (...)) as 'Foo1',
    (SELECT count(*) FROM Master2 WHERE (...)) as 'Foo2',
    (select count(*) FROM Master3 WHERE (...)) as 'Foo3'
```

Comment: If any one of these statement returns 1 i have to stop the process
Pls. i want to know the better way

Comment: Then declare individual variables and check the result after each assignment, *then* return the bunch as a result set, as per above. Is that clear?

Comment: No, the only other way would be to append the items with some delimiter like ",", but this would be really bad practice. The best idea is to return the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

You want to only run if none of these exist.

You could use the EXISTS keyword.

Something like this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS SELECT ID FROM Master1 WHERE (...)
  IF NOT EXISTS SELECT ID FROM Master2 WHERE (...)
    IF NOT EXISTS SELECT ID FROM Master3 WHERE (...)
    BEGIN
      ..do stuff...
    END
```

Note that I don't use count, if count is zero NOT EXISTS is true.  Select any column to get the query to run.

Can't test right now, the syntax might look like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Master1 WHERE (...))
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Master2 WHERE (...))
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Master3 WHERE (...))
    BEGIN
      ..do stuff...
    END
```